# Replace first char in text column

Tags: sql, string, postgresql

I have codes in a text column, for example, e12312312 E123123123 need to write sql query who make every value in a column with capital E my database is postgresql

Comment: did you try something?

Comment: You want to prefix the code with a new letter, or make the first letter in the code uppercase?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Postgres string function `initcap()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) to turn the first character of a string to upper case and the rest of the string to lower case : since the rest of your strings is made of digits only, this should work:

```
select initcap('e12312312')
```

If your string may contain other upper case letters than you do not want to lower, then you can use `left()`, `right()` and `upper()`:

```
select upper(left('e12312312ABC', 1)) || right('e12312312ABC', -1);
```